# pinescript V5 I'd like to have more than 5 candles of clearance between entry

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, candlestick-chart

[image]

I'd like to have more than 5 candles of clearance between entry

But my code doesn't run

> s = strategy.position_size > 0
>
> t = ta.barssince(ss)
>
> can_buy = (t[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO6pn.png) > 5)

help me please. thanks.

Comment: there are some errors there. Why your first variable is called "s" but you check for "ss" on the second line? also wha't that t1 on the last line?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out.
But this is just a typo.


s = strategy.position_size > 0

t = ta.barssince(s)

can_buy = (t[1] > 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
can_buy = (t[1] > 5)
```

is wrong, just use t:

```
can_buy = (t > 5)
```

This for example works, every five candles it opens and closes a position

```
s = strategy.position_size > 0

if s
    strategy.close("long")

t = ta.barssince(s)

can_buy = (t > 5) or barstate.isfirst

if can_buy
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
```

A dummy example just to show you. Also use barstate.isfirst, otherwise the strategy will never open the first position (cause position_size has neve been > 0)